# Django forms request

Tags: django, django-forms

My Django application has two models. Which are Vehicle and Offer. So users can submit offers for vehicles. When submitting an offer I want to capture user_id and vehicle_id with the form.

**views.py**

```
def vehicle(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        offer_form = Offerform(request.POST or None)
        if offer_form.is_valid():
            instance = offer_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Offer submitted successfully')
            return redirect('vehicles')
        else:
            vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
            args = {'vehicles' : vehicles, 'offer_form' : offer_form}
            return render(request, 'myproject/vehicle.html', args)
    
    else:
        offer_form = Offerform()
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
        args = {'vehicles' : vehicles, 'offer_form' : offer_form}
        return render(request, 'myproject/vehicle.html', args)
```

**models.py**

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=90, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=90, blank=False)
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Offerform(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
        model = Offer
        fields = (
            'name','email',
        )
```

**vehicle.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
                      <form action="{% url 'vehicles' %}" method="POST" id="form-{{vehicle.id}}">
              
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        
                        <div class="mb-2">
                          {% for field in offer_form %}
                          {{ field.errors }}
                          {% endfor %}
                        </div>
              
                        <input type="hidden" name="vehicle" id="id_vehicle" value="{{vehicle.id}}">
              
                          <div class="form-group">
                            
                          {{ offer_form.name.label }}
                          {{ offer_form.name }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
              
                          {{ offer_form.email.label }}
                          {{ offer_form.email }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
```

I can get the user with `reqeust.user` but how to get the vehicle_id that the user submits their offers to?

Comment: It is not necessary to assign the vehicle, because it should be automatically handled by the form. Are you getting any errors or problems?

Comment: Yes, this is the error. 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'vehicle'

Comment: @User please show the code for `Offerform` and relevant parts of the template where you show this form.

Comment: @User also please add the full error traceback to the question

Comment: I'm new to Django and I get this error 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'vehicle' when I added this line instance.vehicle = request.vehicle to views.py

Comment: But without `instance.vehicle` line I'm getting (1048, "Column 'car_id' cannot be null")

Comment: @User is there a reason why you don't add the field `vehicle` to the `OfferForm`? Where are you planning on getting the vehicle_id from?

Comment: @Ralf ok I've added the `vehicles` field. Now when I'm submitting the form I'm getting this error `The view myproject.views.vehicle didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`

Comment: you need to add in your view a `return render(request, 'myproject/vehicle.html', ...)` for the case when the form is not valid

Comment: @Ralf Thank you. Actually, add `vehicle` to the `Offerform` was what I needed.